# Removing extra spaces between words

Tags: python, text

I have a series of company names, which have extra spaces before/after/in between the words. 
For example:

```
Current Data:
Vendor Parent Company
"ABC Company    "
"123    Company    "
"    CDF,   Inc  "

What I want:
Vendor Parent Company
"ABC Company"
"123 Company"
"CDF, Inc"
```

I have used str.strip() to get rid of the spaces before and after the text, but I can't find a way to get rid of the spaces between the words `(ex: "ABC  Comp")`.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-FrançoisFabre , sorry for the duplicate question. I tried using regrex but it wasnt working out..found the issue, it was with my for loop.